# How can i access HttpServletResponse as an object in java

Tags: java, servlets, response

I have tried below code and got null, Please provide any other way to handle HttpServletResponse as object.

```
ServletWebRequest servletWebRequest=new ServletWebRequest(request);
HttpServletResponse response=servletWebRequest.getResponse();
```

Comment: Can you show the full method?

Comment: What is the context of this question? Which framework are you using? Spring MVC, JAX-WS, JAX-RS, ...? Where is your code from (component / class, method, ...)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [WebServiceContext](http://itdoc.hitachi.co.jp/manuals/3020/30203Y2310e/EY230211.HTM)

> WebServiceContext interface is one of the service APIs explained in the JAX-WS 2.2 specifications, section 5.3. For using the Web services context, inject a resource by using the javax.annotation.Resource annotation.

Example:

> ```
> @WebService
> public class AddNumbersImpl {
>     // Inject the information about the request that is currently being processed in the wsContext field
>     @Resource
>     private WebServiceContext wsContext;
>
>     public int add(int number1, int number2) throws AddNumbersFault {
>         // Acquire the message context
>         MessageContext mContext = wsContext.getMessageContext();
>         // Acquire the properties
>         ServletContext sContext = (ServletContext)mContext.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT);
> ```

And for `HttpServletResponse` use:

```
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) mContext.getMessageContext().get(MessageContext.SERVLET_RESPONSE);
```

Comment: That is quite a specific answer for such unspecific question :).